# Video Encoding with Java

Tags: java, video, codec, ogg

How do I encode video in Java? Should it be OGG or any other open format?

Comment: Do you want to write your own OGG codec, or are you looking for an existing library to use? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Matt - I think he wants to encode video with Java and wants to know which codec to use

Comment: @John yes you are right ... thats my question

Comment: How are we supposed to know which codec he needs?

Comment: !All Actually i want to make OGG format for video.....

Answer (score 1):

The question is still very, very unclear but I'll answer as best I can.

If you want to do video encoding / transcoding stuff in Java, whatever the (major) format, then personally I think that the best option by far is Xuggler. There's lots of video tutorials to get you going and explaining how to use it, and while it can be a bit complicated to get going once you're past the initial learning barrier it's immensly powerful.

If the question is *should* it be OGG, that depends on your requirements and you'd have to be much more detailed for anyone to give a valid answer.